# How to embed Google Maps photospheres?

Tags: google-maps

"Google Maps - Views" shared with Google Maps a feature that allowed us to generated HTML for embedding a photosphere into another website.

A description of the feature can be seen at: https://developers.google.com/photo-sphere/web/?hl=en

A couple of days ago, Google shot down "Google Maps - Views". That's OK because it had given advanced notification about its plans to do so.
What they failed to communicate is that the Embed functionality would be removed from Google Maps as well.

So the question is: **Is anybody aware of where this functionality can be found?**

Answer (score -3):

I think this explains it but not sure. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#street_view_mode

Comment: While link can answer, its better to add essential part of the link in answer.